# Where is SqliteDataReader in sqlite-net?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, sqlite-net

I'm trying to port an iOS application that uses native Sqlite3 and makes heavy use of `SqliteDataReader`.
On the target platform I use SQLIte-Net (https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net) and there the SqliteDataReader class does not exist.
What are my best options to convert this? The usage of the reader is always code like this:

```
SqliteConnection oConn = AppDelegateBase.MasterDatabase.CreateDBMSConnection();
using ( SqliteCommand oCmd = new SqliteCommand ( "SELECT * FROM ATable"), oConn ) )
using ( var oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader (  ) )
{
  while ( oReader.Read (  ) )
  {
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["someColumn"]);
  }
  oReader.Close ();
}
```

Comment: Why do you want the DataReader class separately? The code you posted works very well. The `oReader` is your `IDbDataReader` object. Better use the ADO.NET version posted by tHand

Comment: And you dont need the reader.Close when you are wrapping it in a using clause

Comment: I'min the same boat - just posted a query on SO with a further explanation of what I'm trying to do  - did you solve your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21490426/sqlitedatareader-behavior-from-sqlite-for-windows-phone-8

Comment: No, never solved it. However your question does not seem to be about Sqlie.Net (the ORM) but about Sqlite in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no IDataReader/IDataRecord implementation in sqlite-net, because sqlite-net is not ADO adapter .net implementation.

You should check examples on GitHub page first. You should not use SQL language, like described [here](https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net). If you need ADO imlementation, there are other SQLite libraries for C#, like System.Data.SQLite (official), sqlite-csharp and Mono.Data.Sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

Ive used the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) ADO adapter successfully in a few projects. I believe it has an a SQLDataReader class. Im not sure if its that same implementation you are after however.